# Getting THREAD 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT...) error when running swift app on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to run an app I've been working on in Swift on my iOS device.

I've run the app on my device in the past and have no problems, I'm getting this problem after running it on the device through Xcode 6 beta 5 for the first time. The app works when it's run in the simulator. I'm thinking this could be an Xcode 6 beta 5 bug but I'm not sure. My device isn't jailbroken, and I've tried restarting the device and reinstalling the app -- nothing has worked. Here is the full error:

> objc[195]: Class _TtCSs20_IndirectArrayBuffer is implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class
>   _TtCSs43_NativeDictionaryStorageKeyNSEnumeratorBase is implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class
>   _TtCSs33_NativeDictionaryStorageOwnerBase is implemented in both /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class
>   _TtCSs25_CocoaDictionaryGenerator is implemented in both /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _TtCSs18_NSSwiftDictionary is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _TtCSs18_NSSwiftEnumerator is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _TtCSs21HeapBufferStorageBase
>   is implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _TtCSs13_NSSwiftArray is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _TtCSs13VaListBuilder is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class SwiftObject is implemented in
>   both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _NSSwiftArrayBase is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _NSSwiftDictionaryBase is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. objc[195]: Class _NSSwiftEnumeratorBase is
>   implemented in both
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib and
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/217E556F-6FB2-461E-BDA5-4E7831E60B81/Project
>   Purple.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined. (lldb)

Any ideas?

**Update:**
I am now getting another error: ld: library not found for -lswift_stdlib_core for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea why I'm getting these, any ideas?

Comment: I think it has something to do with frameworks. This happened to me a couple of weeks ago but my mind is totally blank about how I fixed it. I think I had to delete the framework files that were in the project folders (not in Xcode but where the project was actually stored using Finder). I think I had accidentally put them there. Try this at your own risk btw.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Xcode 6.2 beta when running the app on a device. No error when I run it in the simulator. Can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble. Performing Product->Clean resolved it for me.